# Как уменьшить шрифт в этих дивах?

Tags: javascript, html, css

шрифт категорически не хочет меняться, буду рад, если кто-то заодно сделает грид)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
body{
  font-family: sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
header{
  height: 11vh;
  font-weight: 100;
}header :nth-child(1){
font-size: 30px;
margin-left: 5%;

}header :nth-child(2){
  margin-left: 60%;
  margin-top: -6%;
font-size: 33px;
}header :nth-child(2) img{
  padding-right: 1%;
}


header a{
font-size: 18px !important;
color: Peru;
padding-bottom: 3px;
text-decoration: none;
border-bottom: 1px solid Peru;
}header :nth-child(3){
  margin-left: 60%;
margin-top: -2%;

}


 span{
font-weight: bold ;
}
#section0{
    width: 100%;
   height: 120vh;
   position: relative;
   background: url('bezimeni-27_E1v9oDX.png') no-repeat center/cover;
color: white;
background-attachment: fixed;
}#section0 div{
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
  border: 2px solid white;
  padding: 40px 40px 80px 40px;
  width: 40%;
  margin-left: 27%;
position: relative;
top: 250px;
background: rgba(46, 46, 46, 0.8);
}#section0 div h1, #section0 div h3{
margin: 0px

}#section0 div h3{
  font-size: 38px ;
}#section0 div a{
  border: 2px solid white;
padding: 10px 16px;
font-size: 20px;
border-radius: 60px;
cursor: pointer;
color: white;
position: relative;
top: 30px;
}#section0 div a:hover{
  background: black;
}
#section1{
  text-align: center;
  }#section1 :nth-child(1){
    margin-top: 10%;
    font-size: 40px;
}#section1 .grid{
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: repeat(3,1fr);
font-size: 20px;
}#section1 .grid [alt='0']{

}#section1 .grid [alt='1']{

}#section1 .grid [alt='2']{

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="1.css">
  </head>
  <body>
<header>
  <p><span class="span">DESIGN</span>STUDIO</p>
  <p><img src="0.png" alt="">8 800 000-00-00</p>
  <p><a href="#">Заказать звонок</a></p>
</header>
<section id="section0">
<div class="">
<h1>РАЗРАБОТКА</h1>
<h1>ФИРМЕННОГО СТИЛЯ:</h1>
<h3>от идеи до реализации</h3>
<a href="#">↓</a>
</div>
</section>
<section id="section1">
  <p>РАБОТАТЬ С НАМИ <span>ЛЕГКО И ПРИЯТНО</span></p>
  <div class="grid">
<div class="">
<img src="https://media.lpgenerator.ru/images/245037/bezimeni-3_qwMWvjt.png#size_60x60" alt='0'>
<p><span>СОБЛЮДАЕМ СРОКИ</span></p>
<p>Разрабатываем лучшие
креативные идеи
и тщательно следим
за соблюдением сроков</p>
</div>
<div class="">
<img src="https://media.lpgenerator.ru/images/245037/bezimeni-2_O1bIEFo.png#size_56x60" alt='1'>
<p><span>ТАЛАНТЛИВЫЕ ДИЗАЙНЕРЫ</span></p>
<p>Высококвалифицированные
профессионалы, которые
мыслят ярко и нестандартно</p>
</div>
<div class="">
<img src="https://media.lpgenerator.ru/images/245037/bezimeni-1_OmiiQCk.png#size_60x52" alt='2'>
<p><span>ДОСТУПНАЯ ЦЕНА</span></p>
<p>Гибкая система расценок
позволяет сотрудничать как с крупными компаниями,
так и с частными лицами</p>
</div>
  </div>
</section>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="1.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Можно заглянуть в инспектор, и посмотреть что мешает

Comment: Откуда такие выводы что он забагован? годы практики?

Answer (score 0):

Нужно было просто заменить

```
  }#section1 :nth-child(1){
```

на

```
  }#section1 .p{
```

и добавить класс для того `p`